# Blocking or not blocking (Express.js)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, express, fs

Blocking or not blocking, the question is now:

Here is simple route exposing, a folder that server stores temp images. This method just returns image, and thats it.

```
 app.get('/uploads/fullsize/:file',function (req, res){
            var file = req.params.file;
            console.log("Crap comign from passport file: " + file)
            var img = fs.readFileSync(myPath  + "/uploads/fullsize/" + file);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
            res.end(img, 'binary');
        } );
```

I am concerned with the following line:

```
var img = fs.readFileSync(myPath  + "/uploads/fullsize/" + file);
```

That appears to be sync call. Shall I change that to async?

```
fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, imageBinaryData) {

  //read code here
 });
```

Is this a valid concern or I am over reacting? Am I going to have block say if I have 1000 concurrent users doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should change that to an async call.  I recommend using the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) to make this call, as well as other async calls.

Example (straight from Q docs):

```
var readFile = Q.denodeify(FS.readFile);
```

Then use it as such:

```
readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8")
    .then(function(data) {
    //other processing
}
```

Or adapted to your example:

```
app.get('/uploads/fullsize/:file',function (req, res){
            var readFile = Q.denodeify(FS.readFile);
            var file = req.params.file;
            console.log("Crap comign from passport file: " + file)
            readFile(myPath  + "/uploads/fullsize/" + file)
                .then(function(img) {
                     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
                     res.end(img, 'binary');
                 })
                .fail(function(err) {
                     res.send(500, {message:err});
                 }
        } );
```

Comment: Promises versus Callbacks. There are so many CB scattered in this application. But at the end, I will have to "upgrade" the application for promises.

Comment: You can add promises where it makes the most sense to you.  Typically, as you see code "move to the right", indicating callback hell, you should consider making it promise based.  Further, Q (as you saw in this example) allows you to turn node-style callback code into promised based code.  Additionally, the examples at the Q github page show how to make your code callback and promise friendly, I recommend playing around with it a bit to become familiar, and then you'll be more aware of when it makes sense to "then"ify your code.

Comment: One additional thought here...  Promises in general help make async code look more synchronous, so your code will become more readable, and you'll be able to also tackle tougher problems like instances where you have to wait for several async calls to complete before a finishing and sending a response.  Q (as well as other promise libraries) can aid greatly in accomplishing this.

Comment: Yes, you got a point there. You mentined code moving to right side... I call it an arrowhead. I already used async.waterfall to combat it to some extent. But, for multiple async completion I will need promises :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - we should make async what we can.

"readFile" is fine ! *But this might not be the most important part:*

Additionally the path says "fullsize" and so you should **think about streaming** the files.
You spoke about 1000 concurrent users and it depends how big the images are :

An async readFile will load the whole file to memory. And what if you have 1000 users, each loading >8MB at the same time. Your servers memory might be "full".

For "streaming" I can recommend this video:
[Node.js - streaming 25GB text file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qUZfvt67og)

Comment: Good point Sebastian. I will definitely take a look at streaming option.